# Nested calculated column formulas

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need some help with a calculated column. My formula looks like this, and so far it is working.

```
=IF(Column1="Sweden";[Column2];Column3)
```

But The data shown if Column1 = Sweden, contains a "-" in the middle, I want to remove this "-" from every entry that has Sweden in Column1.

I can't seem to figure this out, I've tried a lot of variations but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is `-` in the middle of [Column2], you can use below formula:

```
=IF([Column1]="Sweden",IF(ISERR(SEARCH("-",[Column2],1)),[Column2],REPLACE([Column2],SEARCH("-",[Column2],1),1,"")),[Column3])
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Same formula with `;` separator:

```
=IF([Column1]="Sweden";IF(ISERR(SEARCH("-";[Column2];1));[Column2];REPLACE([Column2];SEARCH("-";[Column2];1);1;""));[Column3])
```

**Update from comments**:

Use below formula to show the empty calculated field if Column1 or Column2 is empty:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Column1]);ISBLANK([Column2]));"";IF([Column1]="Sweden";IF(ISERR(SEARCH("-";[Column2];1));[Column2];REPLACE([Column2];SEARCH("-";[Column2];1);1;""));[Column3]))
```

Comment: Hi again @Ganesh
This formula is amazing, but it returns a "0" if Column1 or Column2 are empty.
Is it possible to remove this "0" and just leave it empty?

Comment: Check updated answer for this.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!